# Add new edges to a igraph using dataframe in R

Tags: r, igraph

If a graph is created from a dataframe

```
library(igraph)
df<-data.frame(from=c(1,2,3), to=c(1,2,3), time=c(1,2,3))
g<-graph_from_data_frame(df,directed=TRUE,vertices=NULL)
```

how to add edges to it using a second dataframe

```
df1<-data.frame(from=c(1,2,3), to=c(2,3,1), time=c(4,5,6))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`igraph` has a `union()` method that combines graphs:

```r
library(igraph)

df<-data.frame(from=c(1,2,3), to=c(1,2,3), time=c(1,2,3))
g<-graph_from_data_frame(df,directed=TRUE,vertices=NULL)

df1<-data.frame(from=c(1,2,3), to=c(2,3,1), time=c(4,5,6))
g2 <- graph_from_data_frame(df1, directed = TRUE) 

g3 <- union(g, g2)

plot(g3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: ok it works. but will it work also if df1<-data.frame(from=c(1,2,3), to=c(1,2,3), time=c(4,5,6))

Comment: sure does. check `E(g3)$time_1` and `E(g3)$time_2`. Also: `is_simple(g3)`